# java Send email with attachement pdf not working

Tags: java, email, pdf, email-attachments

I've been searching about how to add pdf and send it in mail for a long time ..  but all codes failed with me i finally tried this and it sounded correct for me but it's still showing error
here is my essay :

```
   public static void send(String to, Document document) {
            String content = "dummy content"; //this will be the text of the email
            String subject = "dummy subject"; //this will be the subject of the email
            String receiver="aaa@yahoo.com";
            Properties properties = System.getProperties();
            properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.localhost", "https://fr.yahoo.com/");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });
    
            //2) compose message      
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = null;
    
            try {
                //construct the text body part
                MimeBodyPart textBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                textBodyPart.setText(content);
    
                //now write the PDF content to the output stream
                outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
                byte[] bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
    
                //construct the pdf body part
                DataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(bytes, "application/pdf");
                MimeBodyPart pdfBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                pdfBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSource));
                pdfBodyPart.setFileName("test.pdf");
    
                //construct the mime multi part
                MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = new MimeMultipart();
                mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(textBodyPart);
                mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(pdfBodyPart);
    
                //create the sender/recipient addresses
                InternetAddress iaSender = new InternetAddress(username);
                InternetAddress iaRecipient = new InternetAddress(receiver);
    
                //construct the mime message
                MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
                mimeMessage.setSender(iaSender);
                mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
                mimeMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, iaRecipient);
                mimeMessage.setContent(mimeMultipart);
    
                //send off the email
                Transport.send(mimeMessage);
    
                System.out.println("sent from " + username
                        + ", to " + to
                        + "; server = " + ", port = ");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                //clean off
                if (null != outputStream) {
                    try {
                        outputStream.close();
                        outputStream = null;
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

At frist it used to show me errore about host but i corrected them and now that's the error showing

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

can anyone correct my code pleaze

Comment: it should probably be "mail.smtp.host" instead of "mail.smtp.localhost"

Comment: it was "mail.smtp.host" and i changed it to localhost both not working

Comment: what is the error with "mail.smtp.host"?

Comment: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: https://fr.yahoo.com/, 25; timeout -1;

Comment: Looks like host and port are incorrect. Maybe try smtp.mail.yahoo.com:465. But you should be able to find this out from yahoo.fr

Comment: Still didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You are making it very difficult for yourself!

Take a look at [Simple Java Mail](http://www.simplejavamail.org/) (open source, layer around Jakarta Mail / JavaMail), which comes with a **gmail** example which should be easy to modify. For your case the code would be:

```java
private void sendPdf(Document document) {
    // be sure to enable a one-time app password in Google, so 2-factor won't block you
    Mailer mailer = MailerBuilder.buildMailer("smtp.gmail.com", 25, username, password, TransportStrategy.SMTP);
    // or: MailerBuilder.buildMailer("smtp.gmail.com", 587, username, password, TransportStrategy.SMTP_TLS);
    // or: MailerBuilder.buildMailer("smtp.gmail.com", 465, username, password, TransportStrategy.SMTPS);

    Email email = EmailBuilder.startingBlank()
            .from(username)
            .to("aaa@yahoo.com")
            .withSubject("dummy subject")
            .withPlainText("dummy content")
            .withAttachment("test.pdf", producePdfData(document), "application/pdf");

    mailer.sendMail(email);
}

private byte[] producePdfData(Document document) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

Now you just need to fill in the right Yahoo server and port and transport method, but it should work.

If you still can't get a connection, then I'm guessing you are trying from a corporate environment and you are probably blocked by a proxy (or less likely a firewall). [Simple Java Mail supports proxy connections](http://www.simplejavamail.org/features.html#section-proxy) (including authenticated proxy), but if it's a firewall, then you are out of luck unless you setup an SSH tunnel or something (probably not allowed).